# "von ihm" meaning "of his"?

Tags: meaning

Here is a sentence:

> Sie hielt es für eine Laune von ihm

DeepL says "von ihm" means "of his". But how come? I thought it should be "von seiner"

Comment: You seem to assume once again, that literal translation works. Or how did you arrive at *seiner*?

Comment: It would be more appropriate to ask why English uses the possessive after "of" when it would be more consistent to use the object case "him" as with other prepositions. In other words the exception occurs in English, not German.

Comment: @guidot: Ich denke, bei Umstellung der Wörter "Sie hielt es für eine seiner Launen." landet man tatsächlich bei einem stilistisch besseren Satz.

Comment: @userunknown: I agree, but could not recognize, that this was the adressed alternative in the question. More details there would have helped.

Answer (score 4):

The preposition “von” takes dative. You should not confuse this with the fact that “von” plus dative sometimes expresses something that can also be expressed with a genitive, for example “das Buch von dem Mann” can mean “des Mannes Buch”.

It is curious that English has the apparent double possessive “of his”, but that would lead to a question about the English language.